# How to upload file to an ASP.NET Core controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this client code on web-client to load some kind of file.

```
fileUploaded(files) {
  files.forEach(async ifile => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload', ifile)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err); 
      });
  });
}
```

My endpoint code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromBody] IFormFile file)
{
    var data = new byte[file.Length];

    using (var bstream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        while (bstream.CanRead)
        {
            bstream.Read(data);
        }
    }

    // etc

    return Ok();
}
```

Parameter `file` is always null. How to deliver this file from the client the right way?

Comment: try using [FromForm] instead of [FromBody]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
UploadFile([FromBody] IFormFile file)
```

Use

```
UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
```

And

```
fileUploaded(files) {
  files.forEach(async ifile => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', ifile)
    await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload', formData)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      }).catch(err => {
         console.error(err); 
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: what is fileUploaded? Is it a function?

Comment: It is a JavaScript function, @MatiasNovillo

Answer (score 1):

in the UploadFile method, just, do this

```
//if asp.net mvc
var file1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

//if asp.net core
var file2 = Request.Form.Files[0];
```

Comment: This is a valid alternative to changing the method signature